# Detect support for Label for input

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a set of radio boxes that we hide using label for technique.

```
.input{ display: none }

<input type="radio" id="radio1" /><label for="radio1">Option 1 </label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" /><label for="radio2">Option 2 </label>
```

In my testing of the site, I discover that this technique does not work in Safari v5.1 (on iphone 4).  The radio button does not get checked when the label is clicked.

Short of doing browser sniffing, how can I detect (by css/js) if a browser does not support "label for" attribute?  I have tried modernizr but this is not one they test for.

Comment: label is supported but you're using .input class and I cannot see that in your html. what exactly you want to do here?

Comment: It seems incredibly backwards for a browser to not support the for attribute. That said you should be able to just wrap each radio button in its associated label to get the same behavior. If you *still* don't get the same behavior...

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.  supposed to be `input[type=radio]{ display:none}`.  I am trying to style the radio button to look like a regular button.  But in Safari 5.1, clicking on the button (or label in this case) does not cause the radio element to be selected.

Comment: Actually the point here isn't so much about hiding the radio button (though that is what I am trying to do).  The point is that "label for" isn't supported in Safari 5.1 (mobile).

Comment: Are you saying that "label for" isn't supported *at all* in Safari 5.1, or that it doesn't work if the associated inputs are hidden?

Comment: @nnnnnn: it does not work at all.

Comment: @BoltClock: if I do `<label><input type="radio" />Option</label>`, I can't style the label on `input:checked` and `input:hover` (unless I use javascript).  I wouldn't mind using js as a fallback if only there is a way to check for browser support for "label for".